# sed replace end of specific string in file

Tags: bash, replace, sed

I have a hash file that takes the form of:

```
SHA1(disk.iso)= 43798473890473280573920473902472083947320
```

I need to replace the old hash with the new hash.

I've been trying to modify some old code with no luck:

```
sed -i 's/SHA1(disk.iso)"[^+]*"/"'" $HASH"'"/' manifest
```

Any thoughts here?

*** UPDATE ***

The sting listed above is correct:

SHA1(disk.iso)= (some SHA1 hash here. Note the space after the equal sign.)

Here is the current code:

```
sed -i "s/\(SHA1(disk.iso)=\).*/\1 $HASH/" manifest
```

but still nothing. This does not modify the line in question.

*** SOLUTION ***

THIS WORKS:

```
sed -i "s/\(SHA1(disk.iso)=\).*/\1 $HASH/" manifest
```

I just had the file name wrong. Thank you Janos

Comment: Is this the entire file, or just one line in the file?

Comment: No there are several similar lines for other files.

Comment: so `SHA1(disk.iso)` is the search string you need?

Comment: Yes im searching for disk.iso and replacing its corresponding hash with the new hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
sed -i "s/\(SHA1(disk.iso)=\).*/\1 $HASH/" manifest
```

That is:

- Capture the filename within `\(...\)`, and match the rest of the line with `.*`
- Replace the pattern (the entire line) with the captured filename `\1`, and append the `$HASH`
- The whole thing within double quotes, so that shell variables are expanded.

Here's another variation to do the same thing:

```
sed -i "/^SHA1(disk.iso)/ s/=.*/= $HASH/" manifest
```

That is:

- For lines starting with `SHA1(disk.iso)`
- Replace the `=` sign and everything after it with `= $HASH`

Comment: Hmm this seems close to what I was trying to do, but its not replacing anything?

Comment: Actually, the filename is fixed, the script just gets run over and over and the hash constantly changes.

Comment: If I delete half of the hash and run the script, when I reopen the manifest file, nothing has changed. I deleted half the hash just to make an instantly noticeable change to the file. This simulates a different hash being present. In other words, the line is not doing anything to the manifest file.

Comment: Yes, but I did the exact same thing two lines up with another file which seems to work just fine: sed -i 's/VAR="[^"]*"/VAR="'"$1"'"/' boot.sh This is replacing VAR="OLD" with VAR="NEW". Works great. Just trying to do exactly the same here.

Comment: I should pay more attention to flags... thanks @janos

Comment: @Atomiklan I wrote the regular expression to match your example line with the SHA. Are you sure your sample line is accurate? If not then we may need to adjust the regex.

Comment: Actually no, someone modified my original question.

Comment: @Atomiklan well the sample line has to be accurate. In any case, I added another variant of the same thing at the end, with a slightly more forgiving regex, give it a try.

Comment: OMG I'm an idiot...... You had it right the first time. I had the disk.iso name wrong...... Thank you Janos

Answer (score 1):

You regular expression seems to be strange.
You use to many quotes.

You can just do (if you now the hashes):

```
sed -i "s/$OLDHASH/$NEWHASH" manifest
```

And if you don't know them and just want to replace any line with `SHA1(disk.iso)`,
you can write:

```
sed -i "s/\(SHA1(disk.iso)=\).*/\1 $HASH/"
```

`\(\)` here mean *backreferences*; that means that you save the line in a register, that will be later used using `\1`. Of course, you could write directly:

```
sed -i "s/SHA1(disk.iso)=.*/SHA1(disk.iso) $HASH/"
```

but in this case it would be impossible to write something like disk[123].iso
to match several ISOs at once.

Comment: It cant search based on the hash, because that hash value is not remembered. It needs to search based on the file, and then replace the corresponding hash, but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Two steps:

1. find the right line
2. replace the number in that line with a new number

Typically you do this with

```
cat myHashFile.txt | sed '/SHA1(disk.iso)/  {s/\d+/'$HASH'/}' > newHashFile.txt
```

The first term in `/.../` in general takes a regular expression "apply what follows to lines meeting this condition"

The second part in `{..}` is the command:

```
s     substitute
\d    any digit
\d+   one or more digits (greedy)
$HASH replace with the contents of the $HASH variable
```